# Imaginary lines

Tags: coordinate-systems

I tried to get a new definition for imaginary lines-
Consider a point source emitting light continuously. The paths which light does not traverse are imaginary.

Is this right?

The actual definition is this: Any line with non-real coordinates is imaginary.

Comment: Since you want to get a new definition, you might want to tell us what the 'old' one is so that we can compare both definitions and tell you if they are equivalent. Apart from this, if you want to make a definition of a mathematical object, you will in general need no reference to physical phenomena.

Comment: Ok, it is my first try!

Comment: But yes, you are right,  the definition should have no reference to physical phenomena.